# WeekOfYear in X++ using .net lib

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2009

```
 static void Job5(Args _args)
    {
     int i;
     System.DateTime netDttm;
     System.Int32 intnet;
    ;
     netDttm = new System.DateTime(2011,03,20 ,13,44,55);
     intnet = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(netDttm, Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Sunday);

     i = intnet;

     info(int2str(i));
   }
```

I tried the in vb.net it works fine but doing the same in x++(using .net lib) it shows syntax error..All I am trying is to get the week no. from a supplied date. Any insight would be appreciated.

P.S. I found another solution to this which is I created a dll file in VS .net and added this to Reference node(AOT)of AX. It has shorten the code in AX 
   `static void Job5(Args _args)
    {
    weekofyear.wof asd; 
    ;
    asd = new weekofyear.Wof();
    print asd.weekofyr(today());
    pause;
    }`

Comment: just a "syntax error" msg is displayed.

Comment: Please show us the *complete* message, including any mysterious numeric codes, numbers that don't look like they make sense, etc.

Comment: http://www.imageupload.org/?d=4D91B2EC1 i have uploaded the screenShot here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
int i;
     System.DateTime netDttm;
     System.Int32 intnet;
     System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo;
     System.Globalization.Calendar    calendar;
     System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule calWeekRule
    ;
     netDttm = new System.DateTime(2011,03,20 ,13,44,55);
     cultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo::get_CurrentCulture();
     calendar  = cultureInfo.get_Calendar();
     intnet = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(netDttm, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule::FirstFourDayWeek, System.DayOfWeek::Sunday);

     i = intnet;

 info(int2str(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

[Note to any future readers: The following described an error in the original code Indranil posted; it does not apply to the code currently in the question, because Indranil fixed this error. The *other* error was dealt with in another answer from someone else :-).]

You shouldn't be passing a string as the first argument to `GetWeekOfYear`; it wants a `System.DateTime` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx). (At least, that's true in ordinary .NET; I don't know whether Dynamics AX does some other magical thing. I doubt it does.)

(But if and when you do want a date in the form of a string, those backslashes `\` should be forward slashes `/`.)

Comment: Thanks Gareth, i tried "/" it doesnt work either.. i changed my code but the error persists.

Comment: Then there's probably something else wrong! Let's see the actual error message the compiler gives you, please.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you load the correct CultureInfo if you expect this code to support word wide locations. Loading the current CultureInfo will load the servers preferred culture. If the user is en-gb and the server is en-us, you first day of week will be incorrect.

To load a specific cultureinfo you can simply do this:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo arCul = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

In the example chosen as answer, the code loads cultureinfo, but the cultureinfo is not used as parameter to the GetWeekOfYear method, which doesnt really make any sense. Instead you could send in the settings from the cultureinfo.

Comment: Not sure if I can edit someones answer. Not even sure that is the "right thing to do". :)

Comment: I think its more about delivering the right thing, setting others to the right direction. Well if thats an issue, you could probably try posting a new answer of your own :) what say?